# How to retrieve results without going through scanner - Zxing/Android

Tags: android, zxing

I'm writing an application that uses the Zxing bar code scanner. I have a button that takes you to a history page in a ListView. When an item in the history list is clicked, i want to be able to view it's results that are usually shown after scanning the bar code. How will i be able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't intercept this function of Barcode Scanner and send it to your app, no.